# Visual studio not happy when commiting on a repo where Husky hooks are present

Tags: git, visual-studio, husky

I've a Git repository, where both backend(.net core) code and front-end(angular) code are present.

I've some hooks that check that frontend files are correctly linted.

But I've an issue, when I try to commit directly from Visual Studio, it fails with the following message:

```
/bin/bash: C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm: No such file or directory
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
husky - command not found in PATH=/c/program files/microsoft visual studio/2022/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core:/c/program files/microsoft visual studio/2022/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw64/bin:/c/program files/microsoft visual studio/2022/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core:/c/program files/microsoft visual studio/2022/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/usr/bin:/c/Python27:/c/Python27/Scripts:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/Git LFS:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files/Git/bin:/c/Users/Jaytonic/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts:/c/Users/Jaytonic/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310:/c/Users/Jaytonic/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Jaytonic/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/Jaytonic/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Users/Jaytonic/.dotnet/tools
```

Inside my pre-commit hook, I've this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

cd ./Src/Central/Frontend && npm run lint
```

So my understanding is that when the hook is running, NPM cannot be found, but `C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm` definitely exists.

The weird part is that I've no issue commiting from Atlassian SourceTree(with "System Git", not the embedded one) or from VS Code. This issue only happens when committing from visual studio.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would bet that the space in "Program Files" causes problems due to not being properly handled

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Not sure what I can do against it? It's coming directly from the windows PATH environment. They are not supposed to be wrapped in quote there, it's how they are installed for most of the program I've installed apparently

Comment: Given that it works *outside* VS but not from *within* VS, it must be something VS is doing, or something about VS itself. What that is, I don't know, but Windows being as crazy as it is, the trick will be to figure out whether it's "because VS is a program written in <language and version>" or "because VS sets variables X and Y" or what.

Comment: @torek Yes, and there is also a lot of tools(source-tree included) that embed some mingw console, so not sure it exactly use the same environment than a command line would.